# Python No module named model in tia.analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code has this import code:

```
   import tia.analysis.ta as ta
```

And this is on **init**.py line 2 in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tia/analysis" after import code above:

```
   from tia.analysis.model import *
```

Then the python **2.7.12** shell show this:

```
   import tia.analysis.ta as ta
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tia/analysis/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   from tia.analysis.model import *
ImportError: No module named model
```

Can somebody tell me why the **'model'** module in tia.analysis is unavailable even after I successfully install tia and using **Python 2.7**?

If somebody can also tell me the solution, I will be grateful.

Comment: Are you sure that `tia` is correctly installed?

Comment: Yes. I already check tia and it was install correctly. But the model folder is not there. And after I reinstalled tia, the folder still not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why that is happening, but I would check the physical location where the library is and see if you have all the files installed. If not, you can grab the tia analysis model folder [here](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia/tree/master/tia/analysis/model). Make sure you have this folder and then try again, hopefully that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall tia from the official source.
Official source and installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia).